# Find the critical numbers for this function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x)=\frac{5x+7}{x^2+x+1}$$

I found the derivative of the function, which is $$\frac{-5x^2-14x-2}{(x^2+x+1)^2}$$

The problem is that I am not getting the correct values. Apparently the answer is $-2.6490$,$-.15100$ when I keep getting $-16/5$, $2$.
Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you don't show your work, we can't tell what you are doing wrong.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5x%5E2%2B14x%2B2%3D0) agrees with the approximate roots you give.  Have you evaluated the derivative at $2, -16/5?$  It is not zero.

Comment: I set the numerator to equal zero since, to find the critical numbers, the derivative must equal zero or be undefined.

-5x^2-14x-2=0
-5x^2-14x=2
x(-5x-14)=2
x=2, x=-16/5

Comment: Your last step is incorrect and the ones leading up to it are not useful.  From $x(-5x-14)=2$ you cannot conclude that one of the factors is $2$.  You need to either complete the square or use the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative is correct so you just need to find the values of $x$ for which the expression is $0$. You can ignore the denominator since the expression is $0$ when the numerator is $0$. So use

$$-(5x^2 + 14x + 2) = 0$$

You can use the quadratic equation to find

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$

where $a = -5$, $b = -14$, and $c = -2$. This gives $x = -2.649$ and $x = -0.1510$.

Answer (score 2):

Once we've figured out that:
$$
x(-5x - 14) = 2
$$
we can NOT conclude that either $x = 2$ or $-5x - 14 = 2$. Indeed, it's possible that $x = 3$ and $-5x - 14 = 2/3$, or other infinitely many possible combinations such that their product happens to be $2$.

You seem to be confusing this with the Zero-Product property of the real numbers. That is, for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$:
$$
ab = 0 \implies a = 0 \text{ or } b = 0
$$

As Null has pointed out, you should instead bring all terms to one side of the equation and apply the quadratic formula.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer!